# Laravel 5.3 - Unable to pass data through mailable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Using backpack for laravel.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $finance = $request->all();
    if ($request->input('shouldPay') == 'Yes') {
        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new NewBill($finance));
        return parent::storeCrud();
    } 
    else {
        return parent::storeCrud();
    }
}
```

And this is what my mailable NewBill looks like:

```
class NewBill extends Mailable
{
 use Queueable, SerializesModels;


/**
 * The finance instance.
 *
 * @var finance
 */
public $finance;


/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
    $this->finance = $finance; //THIS IS LINE 31
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.newbill');
}
}
```

This is the error:

```
ErrorException in NewBill.php line 31:
Undefined variable: finance
```

I tried doing like the doc tells you to (in the controller):

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request, $financeId)
{

    $finance = Finance::findOrFail($financeId);
    if ($request->input('shouldPay') == 'Yes') {
        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new NewBill($finance));
        return parent::storeCrud();
    } 
    else {
        return parent::storeCrud();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FinanceCrudController::store()
```

I was thinking it would be easier to send the email right from the store function instead of going through the mailable, is that possible?

If not, how can I fix the issue going on?

Comment: Your `NewBill` constructor not accepting any parameters, thats y `Undefined variable: finance`. Update the constructor to `public function __construct($finance)`

Comment: Yeah, you were right, however, I'm getting a new error now: **Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/backpack-demo/resources/views/emails/newbill.blade.php)**  This is on my newbill.blade.php: **New bill: {{ $finance->name }}**

Comment: Fixed it by changing the view to: **New bill: {{ $finance['name'] }}** Thanks. Wish I could give you the answer thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct($finance)
{
    $this->finance = $finance;
}
```

try this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, NiceCitizen.  If you can add some explanation of why this approach is best, it will help make your answer more effective.